# Python mouse library to control mouse

Tags: python, timer, mouse, schedule

Ok, I've finished code and it's working perfectly fine:

```
time.sleep(1)
mouse.move(1814, 19, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.click()                                           
time.sleep(1)

mouse.move(722, 196, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.double_click()                                    
time.sleep(20)

mouse.move(894, 923, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.click()                                           
time.sleep(1)

mouse.move(530, 452, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.click()                                           
time.sleep(3)

mouse.move(1580, 454, absolute=True, duration=1)
time.sleep(1)
mouse.drag(1580, 454, 797, 447, absolute=True, duration=1)       
time.sleep(1) 

mouse.move(530, 452, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.click()                                           
time.sleep(3)

mouse.move(1088, 654, absolute=True, duration=2)
time.sleep(1)
mouse.drag(1088, 654, 1115, 863, absolute=True, duration=1)        
time.sleep(1)

mouse.move(1094, 880, absolute=True, duration=0)
time.sleep(1)
mouse.drag(1094, 880, 1112, 190, absolute=True, duration=1)          
time.sleep(1)

mouse.move(682, 783, absolute=True, duration=0)                    
mouse.click()
time.sleep(2)

mouse.move(1689, 643, absolute=True, duration=0)
mouse.click()
```

Is there any way to make this code a function? I mean, define function that will execute these mouse commands. I'd much appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

BTW, what I need to do, is run this code on specific time(every Sunday at 23:59), maybe you could suggest other solutions how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes. Make a function:
def MouseClicker:
-insert all that code here-

and then call it below.

As I can see, everything is hardcoded so I don't think you can automate that.
But you can automate the script to run on your date. Try make a Task for that date(with task scheduler if you are on windows) that runs a bash script with the line "pythonw nameoffile.py" and it just runs in the background.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried creating a function and calling it, but it basically didn't work. I'd try it and write if it's working.

Comment: Hello again. Everything is working, though, how can I check if code is executed at specified time? Yesterday it didn't work automatically, I needed to press 'Run' button to activate Task.

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10 ?